# Not able to load https site through burp

Tags: google-chrome, burp

I am not able to load the https sites on google chrome. I have successfully installed the Burps certificate but still am not able to resolve the problem. However the sitemap is getting populated by the https site i am navagating.

It came with error:

This site can’t provide a secure

site sent an invalid response.

Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.

ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Answer (score 0):

This issue was because of the TLS certificate in the older version of the Burp Suite. In the newer version, this issue seems to be fixed.

Answer (score -1):

In which browser you are trying to load sites through burp proxy?? Bcoz in some browser certificate needs root permission. You can install certificate for user, root, server , etc. So check again if you are giving all the permission to certificate or not. If you are using firefox then install certificate in "Authorities" . Also try to close browser , clear cookies , set same proxy & port in burpsuite and browser.